# Excel export sheet without shape boxes and drop down

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro to export the current page without any formulas or code. There are a few problems.

```
Sub ExportXLSX()
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFileName As String

MyFileName = Sheets("Order Summary").Range("B2").Value & "_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")

If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".xlsx" Then MyFileName = MyFileName & ".xlsx"

Sheets("Order Summary").Copy

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.Title = "Select where you want to save"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.InitialFileName = "" 'Start folder path for the file picker.
If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

NextCode:

With ActiveWorkbook
    .ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value '<~~ converts contents of XLSX file to values only
    .SaveAs filename:=MyPath & MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    .Close False
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

1. Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") doesn't seem to work for the filename.
2. I would like to remove the drop down boxes I have in column A.
3. I would like to remove the shape boxes I use for my macros.

Basically want to strip the document to only dumb text so I can email it.

Thanks

Comment: What specifically doesnt work with formatting your date for the filename. When I try it on my end it works just fine. Are you getting an error?

Comment: yes, I get a Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

Comment: Is the error on the format line, or on the saveas line? From looking at your code I cant see how the format would cause an issue. My bet would be that you are somehow creating an invalid filename on the saveas line. Try using "Debug.Print" or "msgbox" to display 'mypath & myfilename' and try manually creating a file with that name.

Comment: @Brandon Fixed it by doing `MyFileName = Sheets("Order Summary (2)").Range("B2") & VBA.Format(Now, "_yyyymmdd")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove validation by doing:

```
Activesheet.Cells.Validation.Delete
```

(though qualifying the sheet name would be ideal).

You can also loop through shapes within a worksheet by doing something like:

```
Dim shp as Shape

For each shp in ActiveSheet.Shapes
    shp.delete
Next
```

These two steps should remove all shapes, and should remove all data validation.